# Undefined Method `attachinary_file_field`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I've been following the Github repo for [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) and everything goes well until I try running the page - I get `undefined method attachinary_file_field`. I have no idea what's going on, can anyone help? All the JS files are being properly loaded - I cut out the field and the page loads with all the proper js files. Thanks!

View:

```
<%= form_tag do |f| %>
     <%= f.attachinary_file_field(:photo)%>
<% end %>
```

Model:

```
class UploadImage < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attachment :photo, accept: [:jpg, :png, :gif]
end
```

Screenshot of JS Files:
Edit: Imgur Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9j2V.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue my be happening due to a Gemfile ordering issue. Try to move the Attachinary dependency to the bottom (to be last).
Also, please share your Gemfile.